# TableView displaying empty cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

As titled, I'm trying to display some texts in labels linked to a Controller but couldn't display anything but blank cells. Every labels are linked to the controller properly but the cells are still empty. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Date: UILabel!
}
class Controller: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    let textCellIdentifier = "ShowCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource? = self
       tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShowCell")
        LeagueData.single.addListener {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // return team.count
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShowCell") as! TableViewCell!
        cell?.label1?.text = "sample text" //LeagueData.single.schedule[0].team1.name
        cell?.label2.text = LeagueData.single.schedule[0].team2.name
        cell?.Date.text = LeagueData.single.schedule[0].date
        print(LeagueData.single.schedule[0].date)
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your Storyboard/Xib file?

Comment: Are you using a custom cell in the tableview..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShowCell")
```

change to this

```
tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShowCell")
```

or if You use xib, change to

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ShowCell")
```

Comment: ... and if you are using storyboard don't register the cell at all.

Comment: I have noticed this problem is common after merging my work with another branch on Xcode. Is there a way to prevent the problem in the future?